# Customize a wordpress theme to create a sticky footer

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to customize a Wordpress theme (Attitude) in order to add a sticky footer. Unfortunately I am faced by two problems:

1. If there is not enough content to fill the complete page, a grey gap between the content and the footer appears: [Demo](http://lab-test.square7.ch/live%20access/index.php/test-site/)
2. If there is enough content to fill the page, the footer is overlaying the content but I wont the footer to be placed at the end of the page, after the content 
   (if there is enough content to fill the page): [Demo](http://lab-test.square7.ch/live%20access/)

This is my current CSS customizing:

```
body {
   height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
   min-height:100%;
   position: relative;
}
#site-generator {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   background-color: #fff;
   max-width: 1038px;
}
```

Could you please help me by explaining what I can do to solve my problems mentioned above? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try searching Google or SO for "Sticky Footer" Positioning is probably not the optimale method,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Demo 1 example above please add this to your CSS style-sheet:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will allow your `body` tag and it's other children to inherit the `height` of its main ancestor, the `html` tag. Extending the content to the bottom of the page. Make sure to always have `height:100%`for both the `html` and `body` tag, in order to have it work.

For your Demo 2 example above add this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 65px; /* same value as footer .site-generator height */ 
}

#site-generator {
    position: absolute; /* use absolute instead of fixed */
}
```

The reason I use `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed`, is because `fixed` will always be on top in the same position in the browser viewport.